# Requirements for VR 360 player mode

Tags: requirements, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I want to create player with VR mode support (like Cardboard). looking for any special requirements for such display mode, but cant find any concrete list of requirements - only some SDK that provide ready solution.

Here is screenshot from such mode (from `360Heros-360-Video-Library-Google-Cardboard-Ready2`)

[image]

Looks like it's just duplicated video on both parts. Isn't?

So the question - is there are some requirements for displaying video/image in 360 VR mode or it's just simple as 2 duplicated video for every aye?

Answer (score 1):

There is a left eye image and a right eye image, usually just split across the video file. Think of it as a "left" screen and a "right" screen. They could be the same image for mono, or a stereo pair.

Comment: what di u mean under `mono, or a stereo pair`